# Gomukhi mala bag attachment to Sakshi Mala

Tags: krishna, practice, gaudiya-vaishnavism, vedic-chanting, japamala

How does one attach Gomukhi Mala bag, and a Sakshi Mala?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is of help to get you started with japa. I also googled a bit and fished out the sanest picture. Hope you can start till you get directions from several people doing it in person.[image: sakshi mala in 16+4 configuration;]

You just tie it with 16 on one limb and 4 on the other limb.

May your japa propel you.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You are most welcome. You are blessed, for being gracious and conveying thanks. You will achieve a lot!